# Where Are the WhatsApp Backup Database Files?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm trying to get a backup of my WhatsApp messages and copy it to my PC, so that I can view my message archive outside WhatsApp on my PC using a 3rd party app - maybe WhatsApp Viewer. However, after backing up my chat history, I'm having a lot of trouble finding the backup files so I can copy them to my PC. The phone is a Google Pixel 6a running Android 13 and WhatsApp 2.23.12.78.

Inside WhatsApp, I've created a Chat Backup. The Chat backup screen claims it's saved it to Google Drive and also created a local copy on my phone's internal storage:

So I first looked on Google Drive. Using a Chrome on my PC, I navigated to Manage Apps - only to find that WhatsApp shows as a greyed out triangle and offers me no option to do anything except disconnect. I can't figure out how to access the files and transfer them to my PC.

So instead, I looked on my phone. I used the phone Files app to show hidden folders (just in case the files are hidden), then connected the phone to my PC via USB and browsed round, but couldn't find anything. The WhatsApp folder contains only Media. Screenshot below. Even the WhatsApp documents folder contains only a .jpg image.

So I'm kinda stuck. Does anyone know how/where I can access the chat backup files?

Images attached: Screenshots of WhatsApp chat backup screen; Google Drive, and WhatsApp folder on phone, viewed on PC

[image: WhatsApp chat backup screen]
[image: Google Drive Settings]
[image: WhatsApp folders on phone]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have existing Q&A for this query, please have a look!